# Javascript: How to remove element binded to remove button (dynamic)

Tags: javascript

I am currently using an add button to add input from a text box into a list. I am also binding a button to each of these list elements and then appending them to the unordered list. How do I remove the element onclick of the corresponding remove button? Pure JavaScript only.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var elements = [];
  var textInput;

  document.getElementById("addButton").onclick = function() {

    textInput = document.getElementById("inputBox").value;

    if (textInput == "") {
      alert("Make sure your input is not empty!");
    } else {


      var liNode = document.createElement('li');
      var btnNode = document.createElement('button');

      var btnText = document.createTextNode("Remove Item");
      btnNode.appendChild(btnText);

      var textNode = document.createTextNode(textInput);
      liNode.appendChild(textNode);
      liNode.appendChild(btnNode);

      document.getElementById("myInputList").appendChild(liNode);
    }

  }


  function addElementToList(element) {
    if (element != "") {
      elements.push(element);
    } else {
      alert("Make sure the input field is not empty!")
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <head>
    <script src="func.js"></script>
  </head>

  <input type="text" id="inputBox">
  <br>
  <button id="addButton">Add</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <ul id="myInputList"></ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "How do I remove the element onclick of the corresponding remove button?" you aren't  added it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to register `click` event over created button.

Use [`.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove), removes the object from the tree it belongs to.

Try this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var elements = [];
  document.getElementById("addButton").onclick = function() {
    var textInput = document.getElementById("inputBox").value;
    if (textInput == "") {
      alert("Make sure your input is not empty!");
    } else {
      var liNode = document.createElement('li');
      var btnNode = document.createElement('button');
      var btnText = document.createTextNode("Remove Item");
      btnNode.appendChild(btnText);
      var textNode = document.createTextNode(textInput);
      liNode.appendChild(textNode);
      liNode.appendChild(btnNode);
      document.getElementById("myInputList").appendChild(liNode);
      btnNode.addEventListener('click', removeHandler);
    }
  }

  function removeHandler() {
    this.parentNode.remove(); // this will be `button` element and `parentNode` will be `li` element
  }

  function addElementToList(element) {
    if (element != "") {
      elements.push(element);
    } else {
      alert("Make sure the input field is not empty!")
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputBox">
<br>
<button id="addButton">Add</button>
<br>
<br>
<ul id="myInputList"></ul>
```